# WebStorm stops on wrong file when debugging a Node.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm, remote-debugging

I'm trying to debug a Node.js app that runs on a remote server (on my local network). Node is ran with `--debug=7000` and WebStorm can connect to it without any problem.

My app depends on a few Node.js modules, and some of them contain `index.js` files, as well as my app.

When I set a breakpoint in the `index.js` of my app (I mean: a file I have written, not a one inside modules), WebStorm does not stop on it, but stops on **every `index.js`** that is being executed before mine, which is very (very) annoying...

Did someone encounter the same issue? And did someone find a solution?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What version of WebStorm?  WebStorm 6 used to do this to me, but upgrading to 7 resolved it.

Comment: I'm using WebStorm 10.0.4...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Known bug, please follow [WEB-12265](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-12265) for updates

Comment: Thanks!
Is there any chance to have it fixed soon?